# UIImageView UIViewContentModeScaleToFill - image Stretches when using this

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I am using `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` to fill the `image` in my `imageview`. but the `image` looks `streched`. how to fix this?

Comment: set UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fill in the imageview and at the same time have it preserve the aspect ratio.  If you want the image not stretched use:

```
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
```

Find more details [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)